# Error creating git repos using Xcode/OS X Server

Tags: xcode, git, osx-server

I recently installed OS X Server on a seperate machine and attempting to host some git repos.  When I try to create a new project & remote repo with Xcode I get an error -

```
Could not connect to the remote repository because the server was unreachable.
```

If I attempt to configure it again after the project has been created I get this error -

```
Cannot create hosted Git repositories at path because path already exists: /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/HostedRepositories/SampleProject
```

Looking at the server - I can see the repos were actually created, but for some reason I can't connect/push to them.  I have tried this on the machine running the server and another one on the same network with the same results.  Is something not configured correctly or any way to get at a more detailed error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by going into the Xcode service repository settings and enabling SSH access.